# NotificationListenerService StopWorking After Sometime

Tags: android, notifications

I have implemented NotificationListenerService in my app. Its Working fine for First time. After sometimes its stop working and onNotificationPosted() never get called. But once i restart the device its start working. But After Sometimes again its Stopped.

Comment: when your service has been started? maybe your Manifest file will be useful to be posted or some more code. If your service start working on restart this mean that it is started on device boot action. When it's stop, when you open and close your app or something else? Please post more information about.

Comment: Service is started when i marked checked on Notification Listener in Settings. And After Some times its stop working i ve also added the permisson in Manifest file.            Code Snipet: - <service
            android:name=".NotificationListener"
            android:label="@string/service_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
 </intent-filter>
 </service>

Comment: I think you are using GCM. RIght? If not, could you elaborate how you are triggering/creating notification?

Comment: @Sufian Yes i am using GCM.

Comment: I think you are facing the bug defined under the heading "Unrealistic GCM Heartbeat Interval" in [this article](http://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/).

Comment: @Sufian but without GCM also i have checked its stop working after sometimes. and onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){ } never get called.

Comment: Your `NotificationListenerService` may have stopped then. I'm not sure but it could be because of apps like Greenify or something.

Comment: Did you find the answer of you question @ShekharKumar because I am facing similar problem with my app

Comment: @ShekharKumar  ,did you found solution of this problem?? i am facing the same issue...

Comment: @Ezio ,did you found solution of this problem?? i am facing the same issue...

Comment: hey @hassanmirza no I did not find any solution to my problem. I ended up limiting the number of notification I am posting and also reduced the interval of notification update. I think the bug is still there but it is not noticeable to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think GC may recycle the Notification service at some stage, and it can be reopen when reboot the device.

Answer (score -1):

This service need to restart device to better working, yes its stoped after while time but if you restart you mobile device and use it without problem :)

Comment: This is not a solution to this question.